# How to get last/previous visited route with iron-router - meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I went to a situation where I need to get the last visited page with iron-router in meteorjs. I checked their docs but didn't get any solution from there. They only have the current() function that's gives you the current route name. Is there any way to get it?

I need it to show specific data when last visited page is equal to the set page.

I tried:

```
  document.referer
```

but this only works when page is refresh.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the last route directly. You could save the current route in a Session variable and check against that, something like this (untested):

```
Router.route('/route', {
  name: 'route',
  onRun: function() {
    if (Router.current().route === Session.get("lastRoute")) {
      console.log('same route');
    }
  },
  onAfterAction: function() {
    Session.set("lastRoute", Router.current().route);
  },
});
```

Comment: Router.current().route is a function, call path() function on route, Router.current().route.path()

Answer (score 0):

Sorry late to response on this. I have make it work. Yes, I used session.

```
if (this.route.getName() != currentPageISet) {
      Session.set("showResults", false);
      if (this.route.getName() == prevPage) {
                Session.set("showResults", true);
      }
 }
```

Thanks :)